# showing index in jQuery

Tags: jquery, indexing, hover, show

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul li').hover(function(event){
    $(this).css({
      'background':'pink',
      'height':'75px'
    }, function(event){
      $(this).css({
        'background':'white',
        'height':'40px'
      });
    });


    $('ul li').on('click',function(event){
      $(this).css({
        'background':'lightseagreen',
        'color':'white'
      });
      var index = $('.content').index( this );
      $('.content').show();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tab-menu" id="tabMenu1">
  <li class="menuitem1">google</li>
  <li class="menuitem2">facebook</li>
  <li class="menuitem3">path</li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-contents">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Google</h1>
    <p>pppppp</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Facebook</h1>
    <p>qqqqqq</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>path</h1>
    <p>wwwwww</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please somebody help me

Recently I learn coding in school and study it interestingly 
However I got a difficult mission yesterday.
matter is making form that if click `"li class(.menuitem1~3)"`, show `"div class( .content)"` orderly /using only jquery script
I really wonder using function(hover and index) 
I can't solve this quiz so anybody help me please 
thank you

Comment: you should be doing your homework not other people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$('ul li').hover(function(event){
  $(this).css({
    'background':'pink',
    'height':'75px'
  });
}, function(event){
  $(this).css({
    'background':'white',
    'height':'40px'
  });
});

$('ul li').on('click',function(event){
  /*$(this).css({
    'background':'lightseagreen',
    'color':'white'
  });*/
  $('.content:eq('+ $(this).index() +')')
    .slideDown()
    .siblings('div.content')
    .slideUp();
});
```

```css
.content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tab-menu" id="tabMenu1">
  <li class="menuitem1">google</li>
  <li class="menuitem2">facebook</li>
  <li class="menuitem3">path</li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-contents">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Google</h1>
    <p>pppppp</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Facebook</h1>
    <p>qqqqqq</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>path</h1>
    <p>wwwwww</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please check the `HTML` structure.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I can solve problem for your guide

Comment: @schoolfood Please accept the answer if you are satisfied.